# Comparing backbone.js and Dojo

Tags: dojo, backbone.js

I'm looking at settling on my JS toolbox. For some product reasons dojo will be in there. Now I wonder if adding backbone.js makes sense. Do Dojo (which does a few other things - I'm aware of that) and backbone.js overlap or complement? What would be the conceptual differences in overlapping parts? Are there examples that use both together?
(I know it is a rather broad question and might show my 2nd level of ignorance)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Dojo covers a much wider scope than Backbone.js.
If you are already proficient with Dojo then the only reason you would want to consider Backbone.js in your toolbox is because it is lightweight. You may or may not like the API difference - it is purely a matter of choice.
If you are already using Dojo in a project, then there is really no point using Backbone.js in the same project because Dojo has all you need to build an MVC architecture although at a surfacial level it might not be so obvious. Dojo data stores are powerful and Dijit widgets are designed to be used with Dojo datastores. Using Backbone models for providing data backend for Dijit widgets would be very cumbersome. That is really unnecessary because in Dojo data layer and presentation layer are very neatly decoupled and works excellently out of the box.
However if you just require a lightweight MVC structure for your app then Backbone.js might provide you a lighter alternative than using Dojo.But again depending on your app and your requirements one may be more appropriate than other...

Answer (score 13):

I have previous Backbonejs experience, but I'm about to work on a project that depends on Dojo and I'm just starting to pick it out. Nevertheless I'll comment here what I have observed so far albeit it is little.

We are looking to have a *Modern Web App* architecture style (think twitter, quora, gmail), these kinds of architecture can easily be provided by something like Backbonejs. The concepts it empowers you with, although basics, they are to-the-point in what you need.

To be honest, I don't think that Dojo really provides out of the box everything Backbonejs gives you, take this example: Routers and Views, and the useful methods they provide for easily and quickly declare events, trigger methods on url changes, etc.

On Dojo's side, I'll acknowledge that the stores are there, and that you can connect them to widgets, but that isn't the same as having the abstract Models & Collections that Backbonejs provides. In the MVC tutorial in Dojo's site they equate a store to a model; that would be a Collection in Backbonejs, also you still have a Model (this would be only an item from the store, and you can listen & trigger events from & on it).

It would seem the Backbonejs abstractions are more fine grained.

So I think it is possible to use both complementarily. Just started with this approach, will see how it goes in a couple of days.

(Rumor: I heard somewhere that Dojo is making some developments in the MVC area to be on par with what Backbonejs offers...)

Comment: please share you experience as you learn by updating this answer

Comment: Dojo 1.7 was just released yesterday, and now they include a [router!](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate/blob/amd1.7/src/js/dbp/Router.js)

I've been playing with widgets creation and they are pretty well architected, have good facilities for inter-component communication (events, pub/sub), good separation of concerns also.

Comment: And with Dojo 1.7 you can have event delegation, backbonejs views' style: [dojo/on](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on)

Comment: I'm coming at this question from the other direction now, knowing Dojo quite well and looking into Backbone. Given this answer, it seems worth pointing out that Dojo 1.8 is adding a whole ton of stuff, including some huge reworkings in the dojox/mvc area. http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.8